# Why is the total not updating when a new value is place in the number input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what I have so far but I'm stuck because I cannot get the input elements to change the amount when the number of the quantity is changed.

```js
function calculateTotal(quantity, price) {

  var total = quantity * price;

  return total;

}



function makeRow() {

  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    var total = calculateTotal(quantities[i], prices[i]);

    outputCartRow(filenames[i], titles[i], quantities[i], prices[i], total);

  }

}



function outputCartRow(file, title, quantity, price, total) {

  var content = "<tr><td><img src='" + file + "' class='photo' /></td>";

  content += "<td>" + title + "</td>";

  content += "<td><input class='quant' type='number' value='1'             
  onchange = 'newAmount' / > < /td>";

  content += "<td>" + price + "</td>";

  content += "<td class='amount'>" + total + "</td></tr>";



  var section = document.querySelector(".rows").innerHTML;

  document.querySelector(".rows").innerHTML = section + content;

}



function newAmount() {



  var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quant");

  var quantity1 = quantity[0];

  var quantity2 = quantity[1];

  var quantity3 = quantity[2];



  var amount1 = calculateTotal(quantity1, 80);

  var amount2 = calculateTotal(quantity2, 125);

  var amount3 = calculateTotal(quantity3, 75);



  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("amount");

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    items[i] = amount1;

  }





}



$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input").change(function() {

    alert("The text has been changed.");

  });

});





js data;





var filenames = ["images/106020.jpg", "images/116010.jpg", "images/120010.jpg"];

var titles = ["Girl with a Pearl Earring", "Artist Holding a Thistle", "Portrait of Eleanor of Toledo"];

var quantities = [1, 1, 1];

var prices = [80, 125, 75];
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum- 
    scale=1.0,width=device-width">

  <title>Chapter 08 - Project 01</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="js/data.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>

  <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>

</head>

<body onload="makeRow();">

  <div class="title">

    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

  </div>

  <table class="table-fill">

    <thead>

      <tr>

        <th colspan="2">Product</th>

        <th>#</th>

        <th>Price</th>

        <th>Amount</th>

      </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody class="rows">



      <tbody>



        <tr class="totals">

          <td colspan="4">Subtotal</td>

          <td>$515.00</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="totals">

          <td colspan="4">Tax</td>

          <td>$51.50</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="totals">

          <td colspan="4">Shipping</td>

          <td>$40.00</td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="totals focus">

          <td colspan="4">Grand Total</td>

          <td>$606.50</td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use the "length" property to find out how many elements are currently in the array (i.e. `quantity.length`) and then write a loop to go through each one in turn and run the calculation. Then you don't need to know how many elements there are in advance.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, that is useful but it doesn't help me with the input element. I need to know how to trigger a function when the input value is changed. I have tried the attributes onchange and oninput but neither trigger the function.

Comment: Do you mean every time the user types a new character (or deletes one), or just when they've finished inputting?

Comment: BTW in the code it'd need to be `onchange = 'newAmount()'` - i.e. add the `()` brackets, so that the function is actually executed when the event happens..

Comment: @Adyson I think you just solved my issue. Thank you Very much!

Comment: @Mae_27 Actually the event property `.onchange = newAmount` is the correct syntax. It's one of the few circumstances in which the parenthesis are omitted. The reason being is when the JS engine sees `()` it will execute whatever is in the `(`...`)` as a function. When it sees `onchange = newAmount` with no `()` it will not be executed until a user actually interacts with be triggering a change event. A change event occurs when a user enters or clicks a form control **and** `onfocus/blur` event is triggered (basically when the user clicks/focuses on another element). The `change` event cont....

Comment: ...cont. applies only to form controls (`input`, `output`, `textarea`, `form`, select`, `button`). There's a more immediate form event called `input` that triggers as soon as the user types or clicks a form control.

Comment: @zer00ne You said "Actually the event property .onchange = newAmount is the correct syntax". No, that's only true when using `addEventListener` to declare the handler. Not when you're delcaring an inline event handler attribute in the HTML, as in the OP's code. That's what I was referring to. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6omd5ysa/

Comment: @ADyson if your comment was about attribute then you are correct, but `addEventListener` isn't the only thing to omit the `()` , [on event properties have that syntax as well](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#possible-mistakes).

Comment: @zer00ne My comment was about the attribute yes, because that's what the OP's code is creating. My demo is also specific to that scenario, if you looked at it. (I was thinking of the line `content += "<td><input class='quant' type='number' value='1'             
  onchange = 'newAmount' / > < /td>";` where a HTML element string is being built with the onchange as an attribute of the element). And the OP's comment in this thread backs this up by saying my suggestion fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `<form>` tag

IMO if using more than one **form control<sup>✱</sup>** on a page, a `<form>` tag should be wrapped around everything. There are several advantages when you use a `<form>` tag:

- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) and [**HTMLFormElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) interface allows us to access form controls with a simple and terse syntax. Compare:

**Common Procedure**

> ```
> // Reference <form> by #id
> var main = document.getElementById('main');
> // Collect radio buttons into a NodeList and convert it into an array
> var radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=rad]'));
> // Reference <button> by tagName
> var button = document.querySelector('button');
> ```

**HTMLForm** **|** *ControlsCollection* **|** *Element* Interfaces

> ```
> // Reference <form> by #id or [name]
> var main = document.forms.main;
> // Collect radio buttons into a HTMLCollection and convert it into an array
> var radios = Array.from(main.elements.rad);
> // Reference <button> by index
> var button = main.elements[4];
> ```

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum- 
    scale=1.0,width=device-width">
  <title>Chapter 08 - Project 01</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font: 400 16px/1.4 Consolas;
    }
    
    caption {
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    
    table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-spacing: 7px;
    }
    
    th {
      border-bottom: 3px ridge grey;
    }
    
    tfoot tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2),
    tfoot tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) {
      border-bottom: 4px ridge grey;
    }
    
    .totals tr td,
    tbody tr td:nth-of-type(3),
    tbody tr td:nth-of-type(4),
    tbody tr td:last-of-type,
    tfoot tr td {
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    td.cap {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    output::before {
      content: '$';
    }
    
    input {
      display: block;
      width: 6ch;
      text-align: center;
      font: inherit;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='cart'>
    <table>
      <caption>Shopping Cart</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Product</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th width='10%'>Price</th>
          <th width='20%'>Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="rows"></tbody>
      <tfoot class="totals">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Subtotal</td>
          <td><output id='sub'></output></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Tax (8.25%)</td>
      <td><output id='tax' data-tax='.0825'></output></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Shipping ($3.00)</td>
          <td><output id='SH'></output></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">Grand Total</td>
          <td><output id='grand'></output></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </form>
  <script>
    // Reference the <form>
    var form = document.forms.cart;

    // Data arrays
    var imgArr = ["https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg", "https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg", "https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg"];
    var capArr = ["Girl with a Pearl Earring", "Artist Holding a Thistle", "Portrait of Eleanor of Toledo"];
    var qtyArr = [0, 0, 0];
    var prcArr = [80.69, 124.99, 75.00];

    /*
    setRow() -- passes an index counter and 4 variables
    - Creates a template literal of a <tr>
    - Interpolates variables into TL
    - Parses the TL as HTML
    */
    function setRow(i, img, cap, qty, prc) {
      var R = `<tr id='R${i}'>
  <td><img class='img' src='${img}' width='50px'></td>
  <td class='cap'>${cap}</td>
  <td><input id='qty${i}' class='qty' type='number' min='0' max='99'></td>
  <td><output id='prc${i}' class='prc'></output></td>
  <td><output id='amt${i}' class='amt'></output></td>
  </tr>`;
      var rows = document.querySelector('.rows');
      rows.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', R);
      var rID = document.getElementById('R' + i);
      rID.children[2].children[0].value = qty;
      rID.children[3].children[0].value = prc.toFixed(2);
      rID.children[4].children[0].value = (parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(prc)).toFixed(2);
    }

    /*
    overRide() -- passes a 3D array
    - Iterates through the 3D array 
    - On each iteration it passes array elements to the
      setRow() function
    */
    function overRide(x3DArray) {
      var img, cap, qty, prc;
      for (let x = 0; x < x3DArray[0].length; x++) {
        img = x3DArray[0][x];
        cap = x3DArray[1][x];
        qty = x3DArray[2][x];
        prc = x3DArray[3][x];
        var cart = setRow(x, img, cap, qty, prc);
      }
    }

    /*
    calcAmt() callback function -- passes the Event Object
    - Reference the tag receiving the user data (input.qty)
    - Reference the tag registered to event (form#cart)
    - Collect all form controls into a HTMLCollection
    */
    /*
    - if the clicked tag is NOT the registered tag...
    - if the clicked tag has the .qty class...
    - Reference the <tr> the clicked tag is nested in...
      ...get the index of <tr>...
      ...get the values of qty and prc...
      ...set the amt by qty x prc
    */
    /*
    - Collects all .amt into a NodeList then converts into an array.
    - map() the array and extract each .amt value
    - reduce() the array values into a single sum
    - Set the .totals column values to calculate totals when the user enters data.
    */
    function calcAmt(event) {
      var tgt = event.target;
      var cur = event.currentTarget;
      var UI = this.elements;

      if (tgt !== cur) {
        if (tgt.className === 'qty') {
          var rID = tgt.closest('tr').id;
          var idx = rID.split('').slice(1).join('');
          var qty = tgt.value;
          var prc = UI['prc' + idx].value;
          UI['amt' + idx].value = (parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(prc)).toFixed(2);

          var amtArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.amt'));
          var subVal = amtArray.map(function(sub) {
            return parseFloat(sub.value);
          });
          var amtVal = subVal.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
            return acc + cur;
          }, 0);
          UI.sub.value = amtVal.toFixed(2);
          UI.tax.value = (parseFloat(UI.sub.value) * parseFloat(UI.tax.dataset.tax)).toFixed(2);
          UI.SH.value = (3).toFixed(2);
          UI.grand.value = (parseFloat(UI.sub.value) + parseFloat(UI.tax.value) + parseFloat(UI.SH.value)).toFixed(2);
        }
      }
    }

    /*
    Register the input event to the <form>
    When user enters data to input.qty the callback
    function calcAmt() is called
    */
    form.addEventListener('input', calcAmt);

    /*
    This is a 3D array of the data arrays which will be
    passed to the function overRide()
    */
    var table = [
      [...imgArr],
      [...capArr],
      [...qtyArr],
      [...prcArr]
    ];

    // Call the overRide() function -- pass the table array
    overRide(table);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```